# Android Pushnotification, does nothing on click when inside app

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to launch an activity, when push notification is clicked.
Interestingly, when the app is closed, and no activity is in background, and I recieve a push, I click on it and the required activity is opened.
But when any activity of the app is opened, and I recieve a push, clicking on it does nothing.
I have tried diff combinations. Also put exported = true on the launching activity.

Here is my code :

```
private static void showNotification(Context context,String title,String text,Intent openIntent)
{


    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

   // Resources r = getResources();
   final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setTicker(title)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif_icon)
           .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                   R.drawable.notif_icon))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .build();

    // also tried .setAutoCancel(true) above instead of cancel
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
       }
   },1000);


}
```

Now, what combination should I try ? Remove the flags CANCEL_CURRENT or FLAG_ONE_SHOT ? Tried already. Even without these two flags there was no result on clicking of notification.

I am running the app on android 5.1 / 5.0 . I have read that there are problems in the notification on these android versions. So I already tried the solutions like android:exported=true and FLAG_CANCEL current. But to no effect.

Now how to make the notification click work and open the intended activity ?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT like this. its work for me

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to broadcast data from your FirebaseMessageingService class

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
```

and receive the broadcast where-ever you want to show the data.

Answer (score -1):

```
/*I tried this code on asus zenfone 2 (android 5.0), it is working without any problem please try this.*/
 private void pushNotificationWithClickAction(String mainTittle,String subTittle,Intent intent){
       PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
       Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(mainTittle)
                .setContentText(subTittle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Comment: I tried your code , but same result. It works for once or twice and then it just does't work. Same is happening with my code. It opens the activity once or twice and then I  move in and out of the app. And again go to home page and it stops working. The click does not work.
But today I noticed that this line is shown in debug, when I click the push and nothing happens :

startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=com.mypackage/.Activities.ChatDetailActivity